# Sum and Division example (Python)

Tags: python, sum, division

```
>>> sum((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
28
>>> 28/7
4.0
>>> sum((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14))
105
>>> 105/7
15.0
>>>
```

How do I automate this sum and division using a loop maybe?

Edit: Maybe I wasn't clear - I want a loop to keep doing the sum (of multiples of 7, eg 1-7, 1-14, 1-21 etc..) until it reaches x (x is the user input)

Okay, figured it out:

```
def sum_and_div_of_multiples_of_7(x):
  y = 7
  while (y <= x):
    mof7 = range(1,y)
    print ('mof7 is', mof7)

    total = sum(mof7)
    print ('total =', total)

    div = total/7
    print ('div =', int(div), '\n')

    y = y+7     # increase y

x = 70
sum_and_div_of_multiples_of_7(x)
```

Comment: It seems a little late in the semester for a problem this easy to be homework, but it doesn't seem like a real-world problem, either.

Comment: @Chris: I deleted my comment on your comment as I saw yours was deleted ... no again your comment to my deleted one ... maybe some confusion for later historians.

Comment: @craig: Just started learning programming, but can't construct loops just yet. :)

Comment: @kai - Let's just delete our comments and then send new comments at each other telling each other about the deletions. I'm in a silly mood right now.

Comment: so what is x, the sum or the quotient, that is in the first example, is x = 28 or 4?

Comment: You might notice that the `range` and `sum` are quite slow for bigger numbers, In that case you should use the **Triangular Number** formula given by BJ.

Comment: I don't know if it's me running some different version of python but everyone in here seems to get the "correct" results by using range(7), but when I run it they always return 0-6 not 1-7. Also, it's easy to figure it out when someone gives you the answer on how to do it .. -1

Comment: @Kai1968, @Chris Lutz: There is no use for history of comments.  Please just delete all irrelevant comments.  80% of users just read the question title.  Of the remaining 20%, 80% read the text of the question.  (You can tell by the number of duplicate questions that get asked every day.)  No one seriously cares about the history.   Please delete the comments that refer to deleted comments.

Comment: @S.Lott + Chris: I know I shouldn't comment S. Lott's comment, cause when Chris and I delete our former comments S. Lott has to delete his and then this one has to be deleted too. But now I did. IMPORTANT: Don't refer to this comment in a new comment or you'll have some deletion-work in the future.

Comment: And by the way: Is this still a question?

Comment: @kai1968: "But now I did"??  If you're referring to useless comments.  Yes, you have posted useless and confusing comments.  If you're referring to deleting your comments, you did not actually delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sumdiv7(limit):
    for i in range(limit):
        result = sum(range(i*7)) / 7
        print "For", i, ", sumdiv = ", result
```

Example:

```
>>> sumdiv7(4)
For 0 , sumdiv =  0
For 1 , sumdiv =  3
For 2 , sumdiv =  13
For 3 , sumdiv =  30
```

The trick is very simple, you want to sum multiples of 7,

To get the ith multiple of 7, it's just `i*7`

`range` is a python function to get a list of numbers from 0 to `x`

`sum` sums a list.

Just put these pieces together

Answer (score 5):

The direct answer:

```
def sum_to_number_divided_by_seven(i):
  return sum(range(i+1)) / 7
```

The more efficient answer:

```
def sum_to_number_divided_by_seven(i):
  return (i*(i+1))/14
```

Comment: Though after some testing, it appears that the second solution has some overflow issues. Passing 3800000, for example, produces different results between the two algorithms.

Comment: Erm..maybe I wasn't clear: I want a loop to keep doing the sum (of multiples of 7, eg 1-7, 1-14, 1-21) unless it reaches x (x is the user input)

Comment: @Nimbuz - No, that wasn't clear, because most humans can't extrapolate a pattern from two points. Usually 3 or so points of data are required before the relationship becomes clear.

Comment: but, sum(range(i)) sums the values (assuming i is 7 for example), 0 through 6, not 1 through 7 as i assume you would mean.. sum(range(1,8) on the other hand sums the values 1-7

Comment: @BJ Using `range(i+1)` makes the result for 3800000 agree. It looks like `i` is supposed to be a multiple of 7 and we want the range to include `i`

Comment: Oh, very true. Thanks for fixing that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but maybe it is something like:

```
sum(range(x*7+1))/7
```

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
def sum_of_nums_divided_by_7(num):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, range(num)) / 7
```

Comment: too "clever", and what's that `reduce & lambda` mess? `sum` already does it.

Comment: I just tried to show a brief demo on how functional approach could be used. I agree that pythons in built function sum does that easily. :)

Comment: @neo, it's better and clearer to use operator.add in place of the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem correctly. You want to be able to accept user input - x, and then sum values 1-7 then devide by 7, if the qoutient is higher than x stop there, otherwise continue to sum up 1-14, devide by 7 and check that quotient - and continute in multiples of 7?

My easy sollution is

```
x = input('user input - enter your value here')
y = 0
i = 1
while(x > y):
    q = sum(range(1, i*7+1))
    y = q/7
    print y
    i+=1

print "userinput:  %d" % (x)
print "iterations:  %d" %(i)
print "end value: %d" %(y)
```